# iOS: GLKit matrix multiplication is broken as far as I can tell

Tags: ios, matrix, multiplication, glkit

Here's the source code. `ANSWER` is the correct answer, `RESULT` is the actual result.

Am I blind, or is it calculating a `-1` for entry `33` when it should be a `1`?

Here's the code:

```
GLKMatrix4 a = GLKMatrix4Make(-1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
        0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
        0.000000, 0.000000, -1.000000, 0.000000,
        0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000);

GLKMatrix4 b = GLKMatrix4Make(1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
        0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, -1.000000,
        0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, -1.000000,
        0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000);

GLKMatrix4 ANSWER = GLKMatrix4Make(-1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,
        0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, -1.000000,
        0.000000, 0.000000, -1.000000, 1.000000,
        0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000);

NSLog(@"##################################################");
GLKMatrix4 RESULT = GLKMatrix4Multiply(a,b);
NSLog(@"Result:");
NSLog(@"    %f %f %f %f",RESULT.m00,RESULT.m01,RESULT.m02,RESULT.m03);
NSLog(@"    %f %f %f %f",RESULT.m10,RESULT.m11,RESULT.m12,RESULT.m13);
NSLog(@"    %f %f %f %f",RESULT.m20,RESULT.m21,RESULT.m22,RESULT.m23);
NSLog(@"    %f %f %f %f",RESULT.m30,RESULT.m31,RESULT.m32,RESULT.m33);
NSLog(@"Answer:");
NSLog(@"    %f %f %f %f",ANSWER.m00,ANSWER.m01,ANSWER.m02,ANSWER.m03);
NSLog(@"    %f %f %f %f",ANSWER.m10,ANSWER.m11,ANSWER.m12,ANSWER.m13);
NSLog(@"    %f %f %f %f",ANSWER.m20,ANSWER.m21,ANSWER.m22,ANSWER.m23);
NSLog(@"    %f %f %f %f",ANSWER.m30,ANSWER.m31,ANSWER.m32,ANSWER.m33);
NSLog(@"##################################################");
```

Here's the output:

```
##################################################
Result:
    -1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
    0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
    0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
    0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
Answer:
    -1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
    0.000000 1.000000 0.000000 -1.000000
    0.000000 0.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
    0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
##################################################
```

I've spent the last 5 hours trying to debug some OpenGL code only to find this is the problem. I must be missing something, surely. Can anyone spot what's going on, or verify this shouldn't be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um, I got the same result as your "RESULT" matrix.

I did the matrix multiplication with pen and paper, following these rules:

http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/matrix-multiplying.html

This is how I did it using your two matrix a and b:

[image]

OK, I think I know where you went wrong, you must have listed the numbers in the wrong position:

The way you list the number in code is horizontal e.g Coordinate(x,y,z) but in a Matrix, these numbers get moved to vertical positions.

So for example, [ X Y Z W ] should become vertically:

[image]

Now **IF** we were to list the your numbers in the wrong position and multiply Matrix a with Matrix b, we get the same answer as your "ANSWER" matrix:

[image]

Comment: Now I'm really confused. You seem to have transposed my matrices. Are your matrices showing columns from left to right and rows from top to bottom as normal? I thought each successive 4 arguments I was passing to the GLKMatrix4Make function were rows, but are they columns instead? The Apple function definition for GLKMatrix4Make specifies it takes args (m00, m01, m02, m03, m10, m11..) etc. I'd assumed this to be (first row first column, first row second column, first row third column, first row fourth column, second row first column...). Is this assumption incorrect?

Comment: In code, we would write something like coordinate (x, y, z) but in Mathematics, the matrix list the axis in vertical (see my above second image).

Comment: So that's the problem - thanks a lot for telling me, I appreciate it! It seems non-intuitive to transpose the values like that, I might write my own constructor which takes the normal value ordering so I don't encounter this issue again! Thanks for your help Zhang.

Answer (score 1):

Little bit more details on this.

OpenGL ES suppose matrices have column major order. So element order how OpenGL ES reads matrix is:

```
m00 m10 m20 m30
m01 m11 m21 m31
m02 m12 m22 m32
m03 m13 m23 m33
```

Of course Apple's GLKit Math Utilities are also built according to this column majored order. And it may be little bit confusing while you realise it. :)