# OpenGL ES 2.0 Modify Geometry in modelMatrix

Tags: ios, 3d, opengl-es-2.0

I'm working with an environment built in OpenGL ES 2.0 on the iOS platform.  I have elements that are made at startup, so I have the initial points of the geometry.  These points are contained in the model and modelview matrices, but the array that contains the initial points is never updated through the lifetime of the application.  As a result, I can't refer back to those points for anything useful.  Is there a way to get the current 3d coordinates of this piece of geometry some other way (from the model or modelview matrices)?  If so, can anyone provide a pretty clear example of how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "These points are contained in the model and modelview matrices"? Do you mean they are transformed by it? And that you want the transformed world position instead of the model-space coordinates that are generated at the start of the program?

Comment: Yep, that is pretty much exactly what my issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is to get the current modelview matrix at the point where you've applied all the transformations you want to.

```
    GLfloat matrix[16]; 
    glGetFloatv (GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, matrix);
```

This will return you the entire matrix that you can multiply with all the vertices of your model, which will then be in world-space to do whatever you wish :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually, if you wouldn't mind going a little further with this, it might help... I'm using GLKit, what is the proper way to multiply the array of verts that I have with the modelview matrix that I get from this?

Comment: Here's (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9029796/ios-glkit-matrix-multiplication-is-broken-as-far-as-i-can-tell) a link right here on Stackoverflow that has a snippet of code to perform matrix multiplication with GLKit.

Comment: Well, now i have the modelview matrix in an array, and I have an array of all the points (180 of them) for the geometry I have.  I'm not really sure what I'm supposed to be multiplying here

Comment: :) The matrix mult is (rows x columns) 4x4 and 4x180 (each X,Y,Z,W is one column) which will give you another 4x180 matrix.